# How to get filename of imported modules (Including default) in Python?

Tags: python, python-module

A little context: I'm trying to create a module that can safely copy itself and all other required files to another location.

Say I have two modules.

a.py:

```
import b
import os
import tkinter

print(str(__file__))
print(str(b.getfile()))
```

b.py:

```
def getfile:
    return __file__
```

When a.py will then output

```
C:/path/to/code/a.py
C:\path\to\code\b.py
```

**Question:** How, if at all, can i get the path of a different imported module (like "os.py"), or any module without this `getfile()` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access via

```
module_name.__file__
```

as in

```
import os
module_file_path = os.__file__
```

As pointed out in the comments, this won't work for some built-in modules like `sys` that come from the interpreter's core.

Comment: Note: This will not work for some built-in modules, e.g. `sys`, since they don't actually have a single file behind them, they're baked into the interpreter core. Upvoted regardless though; for the funky modules, you just have to catch the `AttributeError` and deal with it in some way that makes sense given there is no file backing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import os
print(os.__file__)
```

Comment: Yup! That'll do it (and makes a ton of sense). For whatever reason the IDE I've been using didn't list this after entering the module name. is there any way to iterate getting the file name over all imported modules (i.e. find a list of imported modules?)

Comment: I'd ask another question for that, but first make sure you search to make sure it hasn't already been asked :)